# Stacked column bar with line

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, syncfusion

Is it possible to show stacked col with 2 line graph?
While interacting with the combination of stacked column and line graphs, is it possible to show the change in each line graph, as we hide couple of elements(scale) from stacked column?

for more context please view this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471416/highcharts-stacked-column-bar-with-line/76236187?noredirect=1#comment134440205_76236187)
might help you understand
Thanks for the help

I tried looking for the example of such case but everywhere it only shows change in stacked column while line graph remains as it is

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a chart with stacked columns and two lines, define a proper amount of series and set stacking for column ones. For example:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'line',
    data: [...]
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    data: [...]
  }, {
    type: 'column',
    data: [...]
  }, {
    type: 'column',
    data: [...]
  }, ...]
});
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jL0sq2vo/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series

---

I don't know how the line series are connected to the column ones in your case, but basically you can use `show` / `hide` series events to apply changes to line series data. For example:

```
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      events: {
        show: function() {
          const series = this.chart.series;

          baseLine1 = baseLine1.map(el => el + 1);
          baseLine2 = baseLine2.map(el => el + 1);

          series[0].setData(baseLine1, false);
          series[1].setData(baseLine2);
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  }
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rg4mdaov/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData

Comment: Hey thanks so much for helping
I am not a developer, but I am doing a research on high chart and wanted to know if this is possible to get done in high chart.
I would really appreciate a bit more help.
below I have attached before and after screenshot. I would like to know if this can be acheive using highcharts.

Comment: Hey @ppotaczek thanks so much for helping

Points to focus
(a)axis value changes with change in stack
(b) line graph also changes with change in stack giving value whatever is left in column

Comment: please look at the before and after 
please let me know if you can help me with this.
https://www.figma.com/file/5OZNQFSeCrN2oQWjoMXOI2/Analytics-with-highcharts?type=design&node-id=0%3A1&t=fZfu3okrvyK86BoI-1

Comment: Hi @Adya13, Highcharts is known for its great possibilities for customisations. The behaviour which you presented, can be easily achieved by using Highcharts.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the dataSource of line series in legendClick based on Stacking column to meet the requirement.

Please find the below attached sample and code-snippet for reference.

legendClick: (args) => {

```
        let value;

       for (let i =0 ; i<clickedIndex.length; i++ ){

           if (clickedIndex[i] === args.series.index )

           {

            value = true;

            clickedIndex.splice(i, 1);

            clickedIndexCount--;

           }

       }

       if (!value) {

       // clickedIndex = args.series.index;

        clickedIndex[clickedIndexCount] = args.series.index;

        clickedIndexCount++;

       }

       chart.refresh();
```

}

After Clicking Legend: Line series is based on visible column value

Before Clicking Legend: Line series based on average of two column

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/z7svdm-z9aah7?file=index.ts

Comment: Please always format your code